# nansum in R for data.table

Tags: r, data.table, nan

Let's start with DT1

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA),
                  c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA))
# 1: NA  1  1
# 2: NA  1  1
# 3: NA  1  1
# 4: NA  1  1
# 5: NA NA NA
```

We also have DT2

```
DT2 <- data.table(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
# 1: NA  2  2
# 2: NA  2  2
# 3: NA  2  2
# 4: NA  2  2
# 5: NA  2  2
```

I want to sum the two data.table, so I would get the following result:

```
# 1: NA  3  3
# 2: NA  3  3
# 3: NA  3  3
# 4: NA  3  3
# 5: NA  2  2
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to store this data as a `data.table`/`data.frame` and not as a matrix?

Comment: I use data.table because I have to do some heavy operations before but I don't mind using matrix for that part.

Comment: Why doesn't the result of the heavy operations produce `0` instead of `NA`?

Comment: In my context, `0` and `NA` has to be different but when I combine them, I have to use the sum above

Comment: The difference between `0` and `NA` will appear when I print the data.table as CSV

Comment: There's one more unfortunate thing: `sum(rep(NA, 4), na.rm = TRUE)` is `0`. I don't know how we can get around this confluence without more robustness checks on your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `Map`

```
setDT(Map(function(x,y) {x1 <- rowSums(cbind(x,y), na.rm  = TRUE)
           x1[is.na(x) & is.na(y)] <- NA
            x1}, DT1, DT2))[]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1: NA  3  3
#2: NA  3  3
#3: NA  3  3
#4: NA  3  3
#5: NA  2  2
```

Comment: Nice. `is.na(x) & is.na(y)` is the same sort of "duct-tape" that I had to use to fix `sum(NA, na.rm = TRUE) == 0`... but don't think we can get around that really.

Comment: Similar to `cbind` and `rowSums`, one could `rbind` and `rowsum` (...these function names are not great...): `DT = rbind(DT1[, r := .I], DT2[, r := .I])[, rowsum(as.matrix(.SD), r, na.rm = TRUE)]`. However, this returns a matrix (which is probably what the OP should be working with anyways).